# Product CSV special character issue

Tags: magento-1.8, import, csv, importexport

I have created a Category with Special character called "Home Décor" http://puu.sh/k2ZOP/0267464f46.png. Now when I trying to import the products under this category, I got "Category does not exists in rows" error. http://puu.sh/k2ZRZ/be1e291542.png

Here is the CSV file screenshot: http://puu.sh/k2ZTX/5de537e978.png. I have try to save the file in UTF-8 Format, but still facing the same error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just copy the data into Google Spreadsheet and download. It's works fine now.

Comment: If you're looking for a better solution, saving the csv as UTF-8 without BOM is worth trying :)

Comment: yes that solved my problem. saved my life. this is really highly recommendable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Which editor are you using? It is known that Microsoft Excel could cause pure agony when it comes to character encoding and CSV handling in general. Try Open Office and you might succeed...

Comment: Or open in something like basic notepad and save as CSV again. Works well too

Comment: I have try with these, but still its not working.